# Alterar segmento de linha em gráfico

Tags: javascript, graphael

Como posso alterar apenas o primeiro círculo e a linha que está ligada até ao outro circulo num gráfico (line chart)? Utilizei o seguinte código:

```
lines.lines[0].attr({'stroke-width': 8});
```

O objetivo é alterar a largura da linha. Mas isto muda a linha toda, e só quero alterar o primeiro segmento dela. Isso é possível?

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/aNJxf/20/